# Codeigniter minimize URLs with extending controller and multilingual

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I've configured Codeigniter 2.1 with [i18n](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/CodeIgniter-2.1-internationalization-i18n) and extended controller.

I've hide the main controller "main" and I kept visible "admin" and "blog" controller.

This urls works fine:

www.mysite.com/ **en** / **functionname**

www.mysite.com/ **en** / **blog** /

This is my problem:
www.mysite.com/ **it** / **blog** / **functionname**

With the main controller "**blog**" everything after "/" is ignored.

Is it possible to do this?

My routes.php file:

```
$default_controller = "main";
$language_alias = array('it','en');
// exceptions
$controller_exceptions = array('admin','blog');
// route
$route['default_controller'] = $default_controller;
$route["^(".implode('|', $language_alias).")/(".implode('|', $controller_exceptions).")(.*)"] = '$2';
$route["^(".implode('|', $language_alias).")?/(.*)"] = $default_controller.'/$2';
$route["^((?!\b".implode('\b|\b', $controller_exceptions)."\b).*)$"] = $default_controller.'/$1';

foreach($language_alias as $language) {
    $route[$language] = $default_controller.'/index';
}

$route['404_override'] = '';

// URI like '/en/about' -> use controller 'about'
$route['^(it|en)/(.+)$'] = "$2";

// '/it', '/en' URIs -> use default controller
$route['^(it|en)$'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

If I remove lang in my URL everything works fine:

www.mysite.com/ **blog** / **functionname**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need another segment in your routes for accessing the controllers function.

so you'll need a second line:

```
// '/it', '/en' URIs -> use default controller
$route['^(it|en)$'] = $route['default_controller'];
// URI like '/en/about' -> use controller 'about'
$route['^(it|en)/(.+)$'] = "$2";
// URI like '/en/about/test' -> use controller 'about' with function 'test'
$route['^(it|en)/(.+)/(.+)$'] = "$2/$3";
```

I don't use the i18n or support multiple language in any project atm so I can't test but this should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but It seems it doesn't work.

I think the problem is here:
`$route['default_controller'] = $default_controller;`
`$route["^(".implode('|', $language_alias).")/(".implode('|', $controller_exceptions).")(.*)"] = '$2';`
`$route["^(".implode('|', $language_alias).")?/(.*)"] = $default_controller.'/$2';`
`$route["^((?!\b".implode('\b|\b', $controller_exceptions)."\b).*)$"] = $default_controller.'/$1';`

Comment: I changed my answer, I moved the default to the top. It will never work with the default on the bottom.

Comment: If I moved the default to the top the main URL doesn't work:
www.mysite.com/it/article

Comment: is article a controller or function in your case?

Comment: Ok, I think I've found the solution with your help. 

I've added this line: 

`$route["^(it|en)/(.+)/(.+)$"] = '$2/$3';` 

Before this: 

`$route["^(".implode('|', $language_alias).")/(".implode('|', $controller_exceptions).")(.*)"] = '$2';`